# How do I set up the remote tracking branch in Egit?

Tags: eclipse, github, egit, git-remote

I have recently set up an Android project on Github.
Everything seems fine except for the fact that the remote tracking branch is absent from the remote tracking folder.

[image: remote tracking empty in Egit]

As a result, I can't push my changes to the Github folder.
How would you resolve this?

Comment: This is a snapshot for the question. http://puu.sh/3Zskr.png

Answer (score 2):

You can check the [Egit user guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide), section "[Configuring upstream push](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pushing_to_upstream)", in order to add a new [refspec](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Refspecs) for the push (accessible through the [Push Wizard](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Wizard)).

[image: refspec]

Or you could simply use a git shell (msysgit for instance on Windows) and type:

```
git branch -u origin/master master
```

Comment: Thanks. I have been looking for an answer to this myself. Will try it out later today as I'm also looking for a remote tracking branch.